# PHP - IF argument error that will not process - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error on the last ELSE function line. A bit new with MySQL coding so if someone could show me how to fix, and why, would be greatly appreciated!

```
if ($password = $old_pw) {
    do {
            if ($new_pw_a = $new_pw_b) {
                $insert_data = ("INSERT INTO #database (password) VALUES ('$new_pw_a')");
                mysql_query($insert_data) or die("<img src='images/fail.png'> Unable to change password due Database - Contact Web Admin!");
                } 
            else { 
                echo "<img src='images/fail.png'> Unable to change password - New Passwords do not match!"; 
                }
            }
            else { 
            echo "<img src='images/fail.png'> Unable to change password - Password Incorrect!"; 
            }
    }
```

Comment: `if ($new_pw_a = $new_pw_b) {` You need to use `==` not `=`

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde But I still get the error?

Comment: You do it more than once. Fix them *all*

Comment: @JohnConde, I have changed them all, but sadly no change to the error?

Comment: And one more thing is to remove ending `{` after second `else`.

Comment: @ANyarThar I have tried this also - still showing an error?

Comment: What's ` do {` here? your code is like `if(){ do{}else{}}`

Comment: @JamesHam Sorry I means to remove `}` approx line 9 in your post code.

Comment: @ShaunakShukla Thank you! This has fixed my problem - successfully confused myself with the DO function. Again - Thank you!

Comment: Is there any condition there? `do` is found without `while` and `else` is without `if`!! So your code should be like `if(){ do{}while(); } else {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
if ($password == $old_pw) {
    if ($new_pw_a == $new_pw_b) {
        $insert_data = ("INSERT INTO #database (password) VALUES ('$new_pw_a')");
        mysql_query($insert_data) or die("<img src='images/fail.png'> Unable to change password due Database - Contact Web Admin!");
    } 
    else { 
        echo "<img src='images/fail.png'> Unable to change password - New Passwords do not match!"; 
    }
 }
 else { 
     echo "<img src='images/fail.png'> Unable to change password - Password Incorrect!"; 
 }
```

Comment: You just have to replace `=` with `==` in if condition.

Comment: Thanks @dipak-g but it is still showing as an error on line 11?

Comment: @JamesHam I have edited the above code. Could you retry?